# Strange GCC short int conversion warning

Tags: c, gcc, implicit-conversion

I have a bit of C code, which goes exactly like this:

```
short int fun16(void){
    short int a = 2;
    short int b = 2;
    return a+b;
}
```

When I try to compile it with GCC, I get the warning:

```
warning: conversion to 'short int' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
  return a+b;
          ^
```

Though there is no visible conversion. Both operands are short and even the returning value is short as well. So, what's the catch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do arithmetic computations, the operands are subject to "the usual arithmetic conversions" (a superset of the "integer promotions" quoted in [Acme's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20236519/1256452)—he beat me to this but I'll go ahead and post anyway :-) ).  These widen `short int` to plain `int`, so:

```
a + b
```

computes the same result as:

```
((int) a) + ((int) b)
```

The `return` statement must then narrow this `int` to a `short int`, and this is where gcc produces the warning.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting the standard (§6.3.1.1 ¶2):

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or `unsigned int` may
>   be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than `int` or `unsigned int`) whose integer
>     conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of `int` and `unsigned int`.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type, the value is
>   converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`.
>   These are called the *integer promotions*. All other types are
>   unchanged by the integer promotions.

The [`-Wconversion`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) flag warns about:

> Warn for *implicit conversions* that may alter a value. This includes
>   conversions between real and integer, like `abs (x)` when `x` is `double`;
>   conversions between signed and unsigned, like `unsigned ui = -1;` and
>   conversions to smaller types, like `sqrtf (M_PI)`. Do not warn for
>   explicit casts like `abs ((int) x)` and `ui = (unsigned) -1`, or if the
>   value is not changed by the conversion like in `abs (2.0)`. Warnings
>   about conversions between signed and unsigned integers can be disabled
>   by using `-Wno-sign-conversion`.

Answer (score 3):

From **The C Programming Language** section **2.7 Type Conversion**

- If either operand is `long double`, convert the other to `long double`.
- Otherwise, if either operand is `double`, convert the other to `double`.
- Otherwise, if either operand is `float`, convert the other to `float`.
- Otherwise, convert `char` and `short` to `int`.
- Then, if either operand is `long`, convert the other to `long`.

Comment: The actual rules in ISO C differ

Answer (score 2):

When both operands are `short`, they are implicitly promoted to `int` in arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 0):

If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

Refer the following post: 
[Why must a short be converted to an int before arithmetic operations in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371868/why-must-a-short-be-converted-to-an-int-before-arithmetic-operations-in-c-and-c)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  I'm not really clear what your answer adds that was not already present other than the possible duplicate.  Granted, as a newcomer you can't leave comments yet, but this is a fairly old question which has suddenly gained some activity.  To add an answer to such a question, you normally need some important new information.

Answer (score -1):

GCC will only perform these implicit upscaling to int on operations which generate temporaries:

```
++i
i += 2
```

will not generate temporaries.

```
i = j + 1
```

will.

The following code:

```
std::cout << sizeof(i) << " "
<< sizeof(i + 1) << " " 
<< sizeof(i + static_cast<unsigned short>(1)) << " " 
<< sizeof(static_cast<unsigned short>(i) + static_cast<unsigned short>(1)) << " " 
<< sizeof(++i) << " " 
<< sizeof(i + 0x0F) << " " 
<< sizeof(i += 1) << std::endl;
```

Will give the following output in either release or debug modes:
2 4 4 4 2 4 2

Indicating that while some things may suppress the warning, they don't actually stop the compiler upscaling to int.
So to lose the warning, stop the generation of temporaries.

Comment: `i += 2` means `i = i + 2`. The right-hand side undergoes the integer promotions as described by torek's answer.    `++i` means `i += 1` with similar behaviour.

Comment: No, it doesn't undergo that promotion. Look at the output... I'm well-aware of what they expand to.

Comment: See C11 6.5.16.2 "A compound assignment of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to the simple assignment expression `E1 = E1 op (E2)`, except that the lvalue `E1` is evaluated only once". Thus `i += 2` is exactly the same as `i = i + 2`.

Comment: I just SAID they were the same, you Fool. If you can't Read, don't reply.

Comment: you said "it doesn't undergo that promotion." but it does; and your answer says that `i += 2` behaves differently to `i = i + 2`  (which is false since we agree that those two are the same)

Comment: My answer's output shows clearly, with both code and output, that ++i and i += 1 don't generate temporaries and hence do not get promoted.

You're right that I did state i = i + 2 will generate temporaries, which is False, as per the output. Amended.
i = j + 2 Will generate a temporary because it has to calculate j + 2 before addition.

Comment: IDK what you mean by "generate temporaries", but in both `i + 2` and `j + 2`, the operands undergo integer promotion.  to compute, `i = i + 2` , the `i + 2` is computed first (involving promotion) and then the result is assigned to `i` (a narrowing conversion). You keep referring to your code and output but that has nothing to do with your claims. E.g. `sizeof(i += 1)` is the same as `sizeof(i)`, since the final result of compound assignment is the same as the value of the left operand afterwards; this tells you nothing about the fact that `i + 1` (with promotion) was an intermediate step.

Comment: Okay, I respect that you're right, but you should've said that 5 comments ago - then the discussion would've already have been over. Cheers-