# ones complement operator with short int

Tags: c, integer-promotion

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
short int x=0x55AA;
printf("%x ",~x);
}
```

Above program gives output : ffffaa55. I was expecting o/p only aa55 as short int is 2 bytes. Can anyone please explain it?

Comment: `"%x "` --> `"%hx "`

Comment: @pat oh, I thought OP asked why `~x` and `-x` produced different results. I didn't get the question - my bad.

Comment: Related [Why must a short be converted to an int before arithmetic operations in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371868/why-must-a-short-be-converted-to-an-int-before-arithmetic-operations-in-c-and-c)

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum `~x` is the [one's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones'_complement) of `x`..

Answer (score 5):

You have:

```
short int x = 0x55AA;
~x;
```

The expression `~x` has the type `int`.

Comment: ... Additionally "%x" is an int format specifier in any case.

Comment: @Clifford: More precisely, a narrow variadic argument will be promoted to `int` regardless of what format specifier is used. (And `%x` is a actually an `unsigned int` format specifier)

Comment: @AndreyT : Precisely ;-)

Comment: if every data type needs to be converted to int then what about char x=0X55AA; printf("%x",~x); ?

Comment: That's slightly more complicated because it's an implementation choice if `char` is signed or unsigned. So, depending on your implementation, `~x` is promoted to either a `signed int` or an `unsigned int`.

Comment: @sharth  Question "`char` ...  is promoted to either a `signed int` or an `unsigned int`".  "If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions"   C11dr §6.3.1.1 2.  This implies to me that an 8-bit `char`, `signed/unsigned` or neither would be promoted to an `int`, not `unsigned`.

Comment: @sharth: If `char` is narrower than `int`, `char` is always promoted to signed `int`, regardless of whether `char` itself is signed or unsigned.

Answer (score 5):

C language never performs calculations in types narrower than `[signed/unsigned] int`. Every time you use a value of narrower type (like `short` or `char`) in an expression, that value is implicitly promoted to `[signed/unsigned] int`. One important detail here is that even if the original narrow type is `unsigned` it will still be promoted to a signed type `int` (assuming it fits into the range of `int`). This is something that should be kept in mind in cases like that.

Note that it is not just the expression `~x` that has type `int`, it is the `x` itself that is promoted to `int` even before the `~` has a chance to do anything. In other words, your `~x` is interpreted as `~(int) x`.

If you need a result of the original narrow type, you have to convert it back to the original type explicitly. In case of `printf`, where explicit conversion won't solve anything (since variadic argument will be converted to `int` anyway), you can use `printf` format specifiers to interpret the corresponding argument a value of narrower type.

As a side note, `%x` format specifier expects an argument of `unsigned int` type. Passing negative `int` value instead is not allowed.

Also, it is always a better idea to use *unsigned* types for any operations with bit-level semantics.

Comment: Even if you cast the `~x` back to `short int`, it will be promoted to `int` again when passed to `printf`.  At that point, it will likely be sign-extended (because the msb is now set).  To get the desired behavior, it should be cast to `unsigned short`, or you should use the correct format specifier.

Comment: if every data type needs to be converted to int then what about char x=0X55AA; printf("%x",~x); ?

Comment: @debonair: What about it? As I said above, in `~x` values of `char` type get converted to `int` in exactly the same way. The only problem is that `0x55AA` will not fit into a typical `char`.

Answer (score 1):

```
main()
{
 short int x=0x55AA;
 printf("%x ",~x);
}
```

Here,~x is treated as signed int.If you want o/p as aa55,then you should do typecast to unsigned short in.so,Try like this..

```
 main()
 {
   short int x=0x55AA;
   printf("%x ",(unsigned short int)~x);//typecasting
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the most part arithmetic and logic operators are defined for int and long, an expression involving smaller types involves an implicit conversion and the result will be the larger type.

Moreover "%x" is an unsigned int format specifier in any case.

There are various solutions, e.g.:

```
short x = 0x55AA ;
short nx = ~x ;
printf("%x ",~nx) ;


short x = 0x55AA ;
printf("%x ",~x & 0x0000FFFF ) ;
```