# Bitwise not operator in C

Tags: c++, c, bitwise-operators

I have a problem with how `~` works in C in the code snippet below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
unsigned char x[256];
int i = 0;
for(i=0; i<256; i++)
    x[i] = i;

unsigned char index = 1;
unsigned char y = 0;

//Case 1
y = x[~index];
printf("%u\n", y);
//Output: 0

//Case 2
y = x[(unsigned char) ~index];
printf("%u\n", y);
//Output: 254    

//Case 3
y = x[index ^ 0xFF];
printf("%u\n", y);
//Output: 254

return 0;
}
```

The *case 1* does not return the correct result while *case 2* and *case 3* do.  It seems to me that `~index` gets interpreted as an *int* and not a *char*.  This would be OK however I do not understand why *unsigned char* get one extended during the bit-wise not.

Compiled using: gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

Comment: `~1 == -2` (assuming a two's-complement machine). You are accessing some random memory that happens to sit at an address right before `x`. The program exhibits undefined behavior, so any outcome at all is in fact the correct one.

Comment: See [C++ - Bit-wise not of uchar produces int](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26101257/1708801)