# What happens when a integer overflow occurs in a C expression?

Tags: c, integer-overflow, integer-promotion

I have the following C code:

```
uint8_t firstValue = 111;
uint8_t secondValue = 145;
uint16_t temp = firstValue + secondValue;
if (temp > 0xFF) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

This is the alternative implementation:

```
uint8_t firstValue = 111;
uint8_t secondValue = 145;
if (firstValue + secondValue > 0xFF) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

The first example is obvious, the `uint16_t` type is big enough to contain the result.
When I tried the second example with the `clang` compiler on OS/X, it correctly returned true. What happens there? Is there some sort of *temporary*, bigger type to contain the result?

Comment: For unsigned types, result is "what it should be" modulo the size of the receiving variable.  I mean: only the bits that fit are stored; the rest (if any) is ignored. For signed types the result is undefined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The operands of `+` are promoted to larger types, we can see this by going to [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5.6` *Additive operators* which says:

> If both operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed on
>   them.

and if we go to `6.3.1.8` *Usual arithmetic conversions* it says:

> Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands.

and then we go to `6.3.1.1` *Boolean, characters, and integers* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. **These are called the integer
>   promotions**.48) All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

So both operands of `+` in this case will be promoted to type *int* for the operation, so there is no overflow.

Note, [Why must a short be converted to an int before arithmetic operations in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24371868/1708801) explains the rationale for promotions.

Answer (score 3):

> The first example is obvious, the uint16_t type is big enough to contain the result.

In fact the destination lvalue `x` for the assignment `x = expr;` has no bearing on whether there is an overflow in `expr`. If there is, then the result is what it is regardless of how wide `x` is.

In your example, “integer promotions” apply and the computation is done between `int` operands. This means that there is no overflow. Integer promotions are described in C11 in clause 6.3.1.1:2.

If you had been adding two `uint32_t` values, then there could have been wrap-around (the specified behavior when an unsigned operation produces a result that is out of bounds for the unsigned type), even if the type of the lvalue to assign to result to was `uint64_t`.

Comment: +1 you and Jens literally answered right after me, I actually waited to see if someone would jump in with a better answer, I originally intended to only leave a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *all* arithmetic is done in a type that has at least the width of `int`. So your operands are first converted to `int` and then the operation is performed. As in your first example, the result is then converted back to the target type of the assignment.

Usually it is not a good idea at all to do arithmetic with narrow types. Avoid that when you can, it only complicates things. Best is to avoid these types completely, unless you have a real problem to store large arrays of numbers, e.g.

Answer (score 0):

In C, intermediate results are done as at least `int`, wider if the input type is long or some larger datatype.