# warning: narrowing conversion C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, narrowing

g++ 4.9.0
-O2 -std=c++11

```
template<class T>
struct vec3 {
    T x, y, z;
    vec3() = default;
    vec3(const vec3<T> &other) = default;
    vec3(T xx, T yy, T zz) { x = xx; y = yy; z = zz; }
    vec3<T> operator-(const vec3<T> &other) { 
      return vec3<T>{ x - other.x, y - other.y, z - other.z }; 
    }
};

int main() {
    vec3<char> pos{ 0, 0, 0 };
    vec3<char> newPos{ 0, 0, 0 };
    auto p = pos - newPos;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the warning :

```
!!warning: narrowing conversion of ‘(((int)((vec3<char>*)this)->vec3<char>::x) - ((int)other.vec3<char>::x))’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
```

But if I do it with `(...)` insted of `{...}` inside the `operator-` function the warning disappears. Why?

Comment: Have a look at the discussion in this [GCC bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44500), especially [Jonathan Wakely's response](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44500#c3)

Comment: `{}` catches narrowing conversions (making the code ill-formed). `()` doesn't. Or are you asking why it's narrowing?

Comment: Yes, why is it narrowing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First, why narrowing? That comes from §5/10:

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result. This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*, which are defined as follows:
>
> — [..]
>
> — Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both operands.

where the integral promotion is defined in 4.5/1:

> A prvalue of an integer type other than `bool`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, or `wchar_t` whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of `int` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int` if `int` can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type `unsigned int`.

In our case then, we have `decltype(char + char)` is `int` because `char`'s conversion rank less than `int` so both are promoted to `int` before the call to `operator+`. Now, we have `int`s that we're passing to a constructor that takes `char`s. By definition (§8.5.4/7, specifically 7.4):

> A *narrowing conversion* is an implicit conversion
>
> (7.4) — from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type.

which is explicitly prohibited in list-initialization specifically as per §8.5.4/3 (emphasis mine, the "see below" actually refers to what I just copied above):

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows
>
> — [..]
>
> — Otherwise, if `T` is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7). **If a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed**. [...]

This is why your `vec3<T>{int, int, int}` gives you a warning: the program is ill-formed due to integer promotion requiring a narrowing conversion on all the expressions. Now, the statement about "ill-formed" specifically arises only in the context of list-initialization. This is why if you initialize your vector without `{}s`, you do not see that warning:

```
vec3<T> operator-(const vec3<T> &other) { 
    // totally OK: implicit conversion from int --> char is allowed here
    return vec3<T>( x - other.x, y - other.y, z - other.z );
}
```

As to solving this problem - just calling the constructor without list-initialization is probably the simplest solution. Alternatively, you can continue to use list-initialization and just template your constructor:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
vec3(A xx, B yy, C zz)
: x(xx) // note these all have to be ()s and not {}s for the same reason
, y(yy)
, z(yy)
{ }
```

Answer (score 19):

A couple of things are going on here. First, the `{...}` syntax prohibits implicit narrowing conversions. So the easy fix is to change curly brackets to parentheses:

```
vec3<T> operator-(const vec3<T> &other) { 
  return vec3<T>( x - other.x, y - other.y, z - other.z ); 
}
```

The second thing going on is, "eh? char minus a char is a char, what is the problem?!" And the answer here is that C/C++ want to use *natural size* for arithmetic operations. That is why you see the `(int)` cast in your error message. [Here is a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24372323/841830) of why it does that (just in case that StackOverflow answer ever disappears, he's quoting 6.3.1.1 of the C11 standard).

So, the other way to fix your code is:

```
vec3<T> operator-(const vec3<T> &other) { 
  return vec3<T>{
    static_cast<char>(x - other.x),
    static_cast<char>(y - other.y),
    static_cast<char>(z - other.z)
    };
}
```

By the way, item 7 in Effective Modern C++ convinced me that there are times when `()` is better to initialize with, and there are times when `{}` is better. Sometimes you have to just shrug and use the other one.

Comment: Clear and concise, explained exactly why I was getting an error trying to initialize a `uint16_t` member with the addition of 2 `uint16_t`s. (eg `Foo foo {x +y}`).