# Why doesn't the compiler warn about unsigned to signed conversion?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, compiler-warnings

I recently got bit in the butt with this code:

```
std::size_t s = 10;
std::vector<int> v{s};
```

Rather than initialize with a size of 10, this initializes with a size of 1 with one element `10`. However, the vector has an explicit constructor that takes a `std::size_t`. With all the hype about "use braces everywhere", I would expect many people have fallen into this trap. This could be avoided if the compiler simply warned that we were trying to turn a `size_t` into an `int`.

Why isn't the compiler required to do this?

**EDIT**: My original code had `const std::size_t s`. Apparently none of the compilers I use warn unless I remove the const. Is this a bug?

Comment: there's no information loss

Comment: [fails to compile here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e2010051a6bc5ff)

Comment: Turn the warning level up, with MSVS2015 that code gives me "error C2398: Element '1': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int' requires a narrowing conversion" and "warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data"

Comment: @NathanOliver Both GCC and Clang don't warn if I use a `const std::size_t` instead.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27877127/2747160): It's not a bug. As long as s is const, the compiler can (and in fact will) verify, that 10 can be stored as int without any losses.

Comment: @m8mble I posted an answer to that effect moments before your comment.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not a bug. See [dcl.init.list]/7 of N3337:

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>
> ...
>
> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except
>     where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after
>     conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original
>     value when converted back to the original type.

Therefore the code is valid so long as `s` is `const`.

Answer (score 1):

> Rather than initialize with a size of 10, this initializes with a size of 1 with one element `10`

First initializer-list  are gready:

§13.3.1.7 [over.match.list]/p1:

> When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized
>   (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> - Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class `T` and the argument list consists of
>     the initializer list as a single argument.
> - If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all
>     the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of
>     the elements of the initializer list.
>
> If the initializer list has no elements and `T` has a default
>   constructor, the first phase is omitted. In copy-list-initialization,
>   if an `explicit` constructor is chosen, the initialization is
>   ill-formed.

So the compiler will first try to create the vector using

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32850363/4342498) by [user5389903](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389903/user5389903) since you have a `const std::size_t s` and its value is within the range of an `int` it can convert `{s}` into a `std::initializer_list<int>`.  now since we have a valid `std::initializer_list` the `std::initializer_list` constructor will be called.