# How/why is narrowing taking place in this code when float is converted to int

Tags: c++, c++11

In this underlying code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bitset>
#include<climits>

int main()
{
    float j=9.03445;   //Even double yields same result
    int i={j};
    std::cout <<sizeof(float)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is narrowing conversion taking place since both `float` and `int` are of **4** bytes? There shouldn't be any loss of bits.

And why this works fine:

```
float j=9.03445;   
int i(j);
```

Comment: Information is being lost; converting in the other direction won't yield the original value. That's the rough description of "narrowing" (the formal definition in [**\[dcl.init.list\]/7**](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7) lists all the cases exhaustively, of which "from a floating-point type to an integer type" is one).

Comment: This accepted SO questions answer [warning-narrowing-conversion-c11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844971/warning-narrowing-conversion-c11) might help. `{}` catches narrowing conversions, `()` does not

Comment: `int` cannot store floating point numbers, so you'd lose the 0.03445 part, if you have written `int i = j;`.

Comment: @geza then how 2nd initialization (direct) is working fine?

Comment: `{}` doesn't allow narrowing (that's one of its major feature). `()` does. Please read the comment above, Patrick already told this. (So it means that in the second case, `i` contains 9, instead of 9.03445, you can easily verify this).

Comment: @geza so it is only not allowing the truncation which other wise works fine with direct initialization or assignment?

Comment: @infinite: exactly.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik In this article http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7 under section 7.2 it says that a constant expression with suitable range, this conversion is allowed in case of list initialization {}, but this code fails with that:: 
const float i=2.5;
int j{i}; **but** this one works fine: const int i=122; char c{i}; **which was earlier throwing error**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158810/discussion-between-infinite-and-geza).

Comment: (7.2) applies to conversions, and I quote,  "from `long double` to `double` or `float`, or from `double` to `float`". The conversion in your code is covered by bullet (7.1), which has no such relaxation. (7.2) allows losing precision when moving from more precise to less precise type - otherwise even something as seemingly benign as `float f{1.1};` would produce errors (because `1.1` is of type double, and it's not exactly representable in binary so it's actually something like `1.10....01`; in other words, `float(1.1) != double(1.1)` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "narrowing" is a bit of a misnomer. `int i = 1; float f = {i};` is narrowing, but so is `float f = 1.0f; int i = {f};` !

Here is the exact definition of *narrowing conversion* from the C++14 standard:

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>
> - from a floating-point type to an integer type, or
> - from `long double` to `double` or `float`, or from `double` to `float`, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion is within the range of values that can be represented (even if it cannot be represented exactly), or
> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to a floating-point type, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the original type, or
> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type.

I approach this by just thinking of it as an arbitrary technical term, not as any actual statement about the number of bits in the value or whatever.

In your question, `int i(j);` works fine because narrowing conversion is permitted when using parentheses, but not when using curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

An `int` cannot store non-integer numbers. So, there is narrowing at the line `int i{j};` (no matter, whether sizeof(int)==sizeof(float). These two types store different kind of numbers).

The `{}` syntax doesn't allow narrowing, while `()` syntax does, that's why your second example compiles. In that sample, `i` will contain 9 (instead of 9.03445), hence the narrowing.