# How to remove narrowing conversion from int to char inside initializer list without casting every argument?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

Here's what i tried to do: (with comparison to `std::vector<int>`)

```
char s = 4;
std::vector<int> i;
std::vector<char> c;

i.insert(i.end(),{s+1,s+2,s+3}); // no warnings
c.insert(c.end(),{s+1,s+2,s+3}); // narrowing conversions of {s+1,s+2,s+3} from ints to chars
```

I know i can cast, but that gets ugly quickly. (especially with more arguments)

```
c.insert(c.end(),{(char)(s+1),(char)(s+2),(char)(s+3),(char)(s+4),(char)(s+5),(char)(s+6)});
```

Do we have to live with this? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Narrowing conversion in an `initializer_list` is a problem. See the answers to [warning: narrowing conversion C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844971/warning-narrowing-conversion-c11).

You can use a helper function to get around the problem.

```
namespace MyApp
{
   char next(char c, int n) { return c+n; }
}
```

and use it as

```
c.insert(c.end(), {MyApp::next(s, 1), MyApp::next(s, 2), MyApp::next(s, 3)});
```

Comment: interesting, but a simpler way would be `char ch(char c){return c;}` and `{ch(s+1),ch(s+2),ch(s+3)}`

Comment: @Puddle, I would advise against that. Use of macros to capture such functions is not encouraged any more.

Comment: it beats `{MyApp::next(s, 1), MyApp::next(s, 2), MyApp::next(s, 3)}` :}

Comment: @Puddle, it depends on your point of view. I was trying to use a name similar to [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next)

Comment: hi again. just wondering why it's "not encouraged"? have you got any sources also? cause at the end of the day it's just a macro like any other. it's no different than if i just cast all the arguments myself. what could possibly be bad about it?

Comment: The most compelling reason to avoid using macros is that it's very hard to debug anything that is defined using macros.

Comment: wait, are you saying don't EVER use macros?

Comment: @Puddle, no. it's discouraged. If you can use an inline function instead of a macro, it's better to use an inline function.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. do you know any cases where macro functions are useful?

Comment: @Puddle, Macros, in combination with templates and inline functions, are useful in reducing the need to manually type repetitive code. The loss in debugging capability is justified by the reduced amount of code. I strive to minimize use of macros but I find it hard to completely eliminate it.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is regular, you could use a loop instead like

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; ++1)
{
    c.insert(c.end(), s + i);
}
```

If it s not regular, you could build a `std::initializer_list`, and then use `insert`'s range overload to insert into the vector like

```
{
    auto elems  = {s+1,s+2,s+3};
    c.insert(c.end(), elems.begin(), elems.end());
}
```

Comment: wouldn't both those be slower? 1. the overhead of inserting. 2. converting a initializer_list<int> to chars (and wasting 4x more memory)

Comment: @Puddle It's possible.  No real way to know without benchmarking it.  option 2 is probably the faster of the two options.  I also put option 2 in a scope so that `elems` is "released" and there is no wasted memory.