# Narrowing conversion from int to unsigned char

Tags: c++, char, int, narrowing

When I try to compile this code

```
struct T
{
    unsigned char x;
};

int main()
{
    unsigned char a = 10;
    unsigned char b = 1;

    T t = {a + b};

    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

> error: narrowing conversion of '(((int)a) + ((int)b))' from 'int' to
>   'unsigned char' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]|

Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844971/warning-narrowing-conversion-c11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operands to your addition expression are undergoing [integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion).

> In particular, arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than int as arguments, and integral promotions are automatically applied after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable. This conversion always preserves the value.

Your `a` and `b` are being promoted to `int` or `unsigned int`, added, and then converted back down to `unsigned char`.

If the conversion is expected program behavior (from your point of view as the designer), you can explicitly cast it to the type you want. An explicit cast is not a narrowing conversion. An implicit cast is. So if we change the implicit cast to an explicit cast, the program is no longer ill-formed.

```
T t = { static_cast<unsigned char>(a + b) };
```

Comment: so... how can I resolve this? btw, i had never heard of this before

Comment: It you find it acceptable, you can [set the error to a warning](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55783) Or just cast `T t = { (unsigned char)(a + b) };
`

Comment: Not sure, let me look it up. What compiler are you using? My first guess is that an explicit `T t = { static_cast<unsigned char>(a + b) };` might fix it, because then the compiler doesn't think you're making a mistake.

Comment: I'm using GCC 8.2.0