# constant expression evaluates to -1 which cannot be narrowed to type 'char' [-Wc++11-narrowing] error

Tags: c++, c++11, narrowing

I am working with old code and I got an error at every `-1` when compiling using newer C++ standard.

```
constant expression evaluates to -1 which cannot be narrowed to type 'char' [-Wc++11-narrowing]
```

Here is the snippet code

```
typedef struct {
    //short     len;
    //unsigned short cw;
    char        x, y, v, w;
} testStruct;

const testStruct testArr[] = {
    {   1,  -1,   0,   0},
    {  -1,   1,   0,   0},
    {   0,   0,  -1,   1},
    {   0,   1,  -1,   0},
    {   0,  -1,   1,   0},
    {   0,   0,   1,  -1},
    {   1,   1,   0,   0},
    {   0,   0,  -1,  -1},
    {  -1,  -1,   0,   0},
    {   0,  -1,  -1,   0},
    {   1,   0,  -1,   0},
    {   0,   1,   0,  -1},
    {  -1,   0,   1,   0},
    {   0,   0,   1,   1},
    {   1,   0,   1,   0},
    {   0,  -1,   0,   1},
    {   0,   1,   1,   0},
    {   0,   1,   0,   1},
    {  -1,   0,  -1,   0},
    {   1,   0,   0,   1},
    {  -1,   0,   0,  -1},
    {   1,   0,   0,  -1},
    {  -1,   0,   0,   1},
    {   0,  -1,   0,  -1}
};
```

I've tried to change the code and bracket to parentheses following [warning: narrowing conversion C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844971/warning-narrowing-conversion-c11) , but I still got the same error. Is there any solution without reverting back to old C++ standard?

Comment: Can you change the struct to `signed char x, y, v, w;`?

Comment: Unlike the other integer types, it is unspecified whether `char` is signed or usigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the compiler, you have to write `static_cast<char>(-1)`

Some things are no longer acceptable with the newer C++ standards, so you have to find a more modern way to do things...

Comment: `constexpr char XX = static_cast<char>(-1);` and then replace all the `-1` in the table with `XX` may be more legible and retain the table columnar formatting better.

Comment: is it okay to just change char type in struct or I have to cast signed char to `-1 `only?

Comment: @Eljay: Of course I would do it the same way. This would also get rid of the magic number -1 and give it a more meaningful name!