# Byte multiplied by byte is int for some reason. Why? Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists

Tags: c#, .net, casting, type-conversion

I have this code and it doesn't work for some reason. I don't understand it. What is wrong?

```
byte dog = (byte)2*byte.Parse("2");
```

I get this exception in LinqPad: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)."

Also what is the right way to write this code? Thanks.

Comment: try `byte dog =(byte)(2*byte.Parse("2"))`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All arithmetic operations on *sbyte, byte, ushort, and short* are **widened** to **int**.
For example, the third line will give compiler error:

```
byte b1 = 1;
byte b2 = 2;
byte b3 = (b1 * b2); // Exception, Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte
byte b4 = (byte)(b1 * b2); // everything is fine
```

So, change your code as:

```
byte dog = (byte)((byte)2*byte.Parse("2"));
```

*For more information*: [Look at this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371868/why-must-a-short-be-converted-to-an-int-before-arithmetic-operations-in-c-and-c)

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying a byte value with another byte value will for most of the possible outcomes render a value that doesn't fit in a byte. The extreme case is the max value product 255 * 255 - while each factor fits in a byte, the product needs an integer to fit.

Answer (score 0):

That's because, from compilator opinion, you're trying to cast to the `byte` only first multiplier, not the whole result. This is because of [operators precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323.aspx) in c#

Try this:

```
byte dog = (byte) (2*byte.Parse("2"));
```

Also you should note that you can got an integer bigger than [maximum `byte` value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.maxvalue.aspx) (which is a const equal to `255`, and there will be a loss of data by such type conversion.