# auto type deduction not working as expected

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, auto

this is much like this question [Why must a short be converted to an int before arithmetic operations in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371868/why-must-a-short-be-converted-to-an-int-before-arithmetic-operations-in-c-and-c)
however there is a sub-question why the compiler diagnoses a warning in one case and an error in the other case ,with the exact same expression.

I really like the use of the `auto` 'type' as in `auto var =`..., but MSVC 2015 CTP gives an error from my code.

The issue is I am `auto`-ing an expression of type `short` but sometimes it's promoted to `int`.

Here's a MCVE:

```
struct MY_COORD { short X; short Y; };
using t_crd = MY_COORD; 

void call_test ( t_crd x )  {}

int main()
{
    t_crd    crd { 10 ,20 };

    auto     x5 = crd.X - crd.Y;
    auto     y5 = crd.Y - crd.X;
    t_crd    crd5 { x5 ,y5 };       // (1)
    call_test( t_crd{ x5 ,y5 } );   // (2)
}
```

The messages from lines (1) and (2) are respectively:

```
 warning C4838: conversion from 'int' to 'short' requires a narrowing conversion
 error C2397: conversion from 'int' to 'short' requires a narrowing conversion
```

I thought this code was OK but it's not according to MSVC 2015 CTP compiler (but Intellisense doesn't indicate it).
Is there some obscure little rule that I missed that makes MSVC right ?

And if so why is the same expression a **warning** in one case and an **error** in the other case ?

I wanted to use it in the initialization of a loop variable like this:

```
MY_COORD pos = ResultFromFunction();
auto rows = pos.Y;
for ( auto i = (rows - rows); i < rows; ++i )
{
   coord c{ 0 ,i };
   ...
}
```

Comment: If you really want a specific type, just specify the type.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin : I want it to trace the type (if it changes) . If it doesn't work in this simple case ,then I can't use it in more complex cases..

Comment: Sounds like you may want something more like `for (decltype(rows) i = 0; ...`? Obvious alternative would be to use a function template instead, so it just becomes `T` (or whatever name you prefer).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: yes ,but that take more typing (and thinking) ,I am very lazy :). But the real questions is ,is my code correct or is MSVC correct ?

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @RSahu: the sample provided has all the info needed. (if not on windows you can comment out the include windows line an uncomment the two MY_COORD lines) if it compiles then my code is right and MSVC 2015 CTP is not.

Comment: The type of `x-x` is only sometimes the same as `x`.  Use `decltype(x)`.

Comment: @Yakk: Can you elaborate that in an answer. I like to know why ?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371868/why-must-a-short-be-converted-to-an-int-before-arithmetic-operations-in-c-and-c

Comment: @Edwin for example , subtracting `char *` from `char *` gives `ptrdiff_t`

Comment: @Bill Lynch: thanks ,looking in to that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arithmetic operators always promote integral types smaller than `int` to `int` before performing the operation. This is mandated in `[expr]/10` of the C++11 standard:

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield
>   result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result.
>   This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*.

The sub-clause from there which applies to your case specifies that the operands in `rows - rows` will be subjected to integral promotion. In particular, according to `[conv.prom]/1`

> A prvalue of an integer type other than `bool`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, or `wchar_t` whose integer conversion
>   rank is less than the rank of `int` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int` if `int` can represent all
>   the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type `unsigned int`.

Since the rank of `short` is guaranteed to be less than the rank of `int`, both the operands of `rows - rows` are promoted to `int`, giving the expression `rows - rows` a type of `int`.

About the narrowing conversion, the standard specifies(in `[dcl.init.aggr]`) that, in aggregate initialization, if the expression requires a narrowing conversion, the program is ill-formed. Compilers are free to diagnose it anyway they like. IIRC, under the simple circumstances like `t_crd crd5 { x5 ,y5 };`, clang 3.5 issues an error while g++ 4.9.2 issues a warning when used with the default warnings settings. Either way. MSVC's behaviour, even if slightly odd, is standard-conforming.

Comment: your diagnose-arguments make this the most complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
short x=1, y=2;
static_assert(
  std::is_same<int, decltype(x-y)>{},
  "subtracting two shorts gets an `int`, not a `short`"
);
// that is how integral promotion works in C++ -- things
// smaller than `int` promote to `int` almost always
int a=3,b=4;
// if you use the "new" {} style initialization
// it is an error to have a narrowing conversion:
//short z1 = {b-a};
// but not if you don't use {}:
short z2 = b-a;
(void)x;(void)y;(void)a;(void)b;(void)z2; // block unused var warnings.
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82bb2fcd9defa441)

The variables you make `auto` are mostly all `int`s, as they are usually the difference between two `short`s.  You then proceed to convert them in various contexts to `short`s -- sometimes in contexts where the compiler issues a warning, other times when it is an error to do a narrowing conversion.

When you replace `auto` with `short` the conversion warnings and errors go away.

Note that `short-short` can easily overflow a `short`.  If it does, the result is undefined behavior (signed overflow is undefined).  In practice, the hardware may do mod 2^n, but even on 2s complement hardware the optimizer is free to assume that no overflow occurs, and that can cause seemingly insane changes to your code during optimization.

A classic example is `int x = (unsigned)-1; if (x<0) std::cout << "not printed\n";` std::cout << x << " == -1\n";`, where the branch of`x<0`can be eliminated as "impossible" by an optimizer (as we converted`x` from an unsigned value, it cannot be negative unless it overflows, and if it overflows that is undefined behavior, so anything goes).

So by changing `auto` to `short` you actually move the undefined behavior that the warnings and errors are talking about to a spot where the compiler doesn't warn you or generate errors.  The problem still remains.

Comment: thanks ,that's weird. But it doesn't explain why I get warnings/error when I use auto and not when I use short.

Comment: @Edwin How does it not?  Your `auto` variables are of type `int`, as they are the same type as the rhs.  Changing them to `short` makes them a different type, and the later `int` to `short` conversion warnings and errors of course go away.

Comment: thanks for the further explanation ,makes more sense to me now.