# How to make gcc warn about narrowing function parameters

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-warnings

The program below involves a function parameter that is implicitly narrowed.  Information is potentially lost.

```
void func(short) {}

int main()
{
    int i = 0x7fffffff;
    func(i);
}
```

If I compile this program (either as C or C++) with gcc using `-Wall -Wextra` I receive **no warnings**!

Surely, this behavior would often be considered undesirable.

Is there some gcc command-line parameter that would trigger a diagnostic message when these narrowing conversions occur?

Comment: the option: `-Wconversion` will allow the compiler to output warning messages about such problems.

Comment: I was just concerned that the compiler might interpret `0xffffffff` as -1, and somehow realize that the value would fit into a short. It was a long shot.

Comment: this question is about `gcc`, not about `C++` (which is a different language) so please remove the `c++` tag

Comment: MSVC objects to something else: *error C2055: expected formal parameter list, not a type list*. That would be OK for the function **prototype** `void func(short);` but not for its implementation, since the code cannot use the argument without an identifier. It was not a warning, but an error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `-Wconversion` for gcc/clang. `/W4` can be used for VC++.

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sX00acMWslm5yReM)

Comment: Note [there is also a -Wconversion wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29796588/1708801)