# Is casting necessary in the following arithmetic sum?

Tags: c, casting, overflow

```
short a;
short b;
short x;
int c = (int)a + (int)b * (int)x;
```

Can I dispense with the (int) casts in this case? i.e. when compiler performs the multiply and add, does it work with int intermediate variables, or with short intermediate variables?

Edit: what about for other types?

```
int32 a;
int32 b;
int32 x;
int64 c = (int64)a + (int64)b * (int64)x;
```

Edit 2: It seems to me that

```
int64 c = a + b*x
```

can overflow, because b*x is calculated using int arithmetic. The safer expression is:

```
int64 c = a + (int64)b * (int64)x;
```

Comment: See  [Why must a short be converted to an int before arithmetic operations in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24371868/1708801)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the case of `short`, the casts are unnecessary because `short` values are implicitly promoted to `int` in arithmetic expressions.

For the other example, assuming `int32` and `int64` are what they seem to be, the cast is necessary if `int` is smaller than 64 bits.  Technically, a single cast on one the the operands to `*` would suffice, such as :

```
int64 c = a + (int64)b * x;
```

`b` is first converted to `int64`, `x` is also converted to `int64` because `*` converts the other operand if it has a lower rank, then multiplication is performed, which cannot overflow. `a` is then converted to `int64` for the same reason, because the other operand to '+' has a higher rank.  The addition is performed, it cannot overflow either. Finally the result is stored to `c`.

Comment: So, is cast performed before multiply?

Comment: @Jacko: of course, because casts, like all unary operators have higher precedence than binary operators.

Comment: Is this cast necessary for 64 bit builds ?

Comment: @Jacko: 64 bit build is not precise enough: the cast is not necessary if the `int` type is smaller than 64 bits.  Most 64 bits environments still keep the `int` type as 32 bits but make pointers 64 bits.  If the `int` is 32 bits, the cast is necessary.  If it is 64 bits, the cast does not do anything, so you should always write it.

Answer (score 1):

From the C++ Standard (5.7 Additive operators)

> 1 The additive operators + and - group left-to-right. The usual
>   arithmetic conversions are performed for operands of arithmetic or
>   enumeration type.

the usual arithmetic conversions include the integral promotion when objects with rank less than the rank of type `int` are converted to type int.

The same is valid for multiplicative operators.

In your example operands of type `short` are automatically converted to type `int` and the compiler performs the operations with operands of type `int`
Thus using of the casting does not make a great sense.:)

As for this code snippet

```
int32 a;
int32 b;
int32 x;
int64 c = (int64)a + (int64)b * (int64)x;
```

then you indeed should cast at least one operand

```
int64 c = a + (int64)b * x;
```

if you want that there would not be overflow.

Comment: Detail: "cast at least one operand" does not help much with `(int64)a + b * x`.

Comment: @chux  To avoid such comments I showed in my post an example how to use at least one casting.