# Why is the common type of bool and int8_t an int32_t in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, boolean, std

I'm curious about some of the behavior of the builtin `bool` type in C++. As I understand it, [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) determines the common type using implicit convertibility. I would expect that an expression with `bool` and another type would cause bool to convert to that type. For instance, I can see that `bool + float` -> `float` and `bool + double` -> `double`. However, `bool + int8_t` -> `int32_t` and `bool + int16_t` -> `int32_t`. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: **integral promotion**.

In numerical arithmetic, small integral types (including `bool`, `char`, `unsigned char`, `signed char`, `short`, `unsigned short`, etc) are promoted to `int` if all the possible values fit in `int`, otherwise they are promoted to `unsigned int`.

On most machines today, `int32_t` is the same as `int`. In the case of `bool + int8_t` or `bool + int16_t`, both are promoted to `int`.

Comment: Thanks Yu Hao! That's great. Do you know where this is mentioned in the standard?

Comment: @user2333829 *§4.5 Integral promotions*

Comment: Thanks, you answered my question! I find that weird, but it's clearly there.

Comment: @user2333829 [Why must a short be converted to an int before arithmetic operations in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24371868/995714)