# Should bit-fields less than int in size be the subject of integral promotion?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, language-lawyer, bit-fields, integer-promotion

Let's say I have following `struct`:

```
struct A
{
    unsigned int a : 1;
    unsigned int b : 1;
};
```

What interests me is the type of expression `a + b`. While technically bit-fields have "type" with size less than `int` so integral promotion probably should happen and then result is `int` like it happens to be in gcc and clang.

But since it's impossible to extract the exact type of bit-field itself and it will always be deduced to be its "big" type (i.e. `unsigned int` in this case) is it correct that integral promotion should happen? Because we can't actually talk about exact types and their sizes for bit-fields except them being deduced as `unsigned int` in which case integral promotion shouldn't happen.

(Once again my question stems from the fact that MSVC happens to think that `unsigned int` is type of such expression)

Comment: Which version of visual studio, it probably makes sense to add that tag in case other people have the same issue

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour It's the newest but I added it just in case.

Comment: Also relevant: [Why must a short be converted to an int before arithmetic operations in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24371868/1708801)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we go to the [draft C++ standard: N4140](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf) section `5` it says:

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or
>   enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar
>   way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of
>   the result. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions,
>   which are defined as follows

and the following bullet applies:

> - Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both operands.61 Then the following rules shall be applied to the promoted
>     operands:

and section 4.5 which says (*emphasis mine*):

> A prvalue for an integral bit-field (9.6) can be converted to a
>   prvalue of **type int if int can represent all the values of the
>   bit-field;** otherwise, it can be converted to unsigned int if unsigned
>   int can represent all the values of the bit-field. If the bit-field is
>   larger yet, no integral promotion applies to it. If the bit-field has
>   an enumerated type, it is treated as any other value of that type for
>   promotion purposes.

So gcc and clang are correct, `a` and `b` should be promoted to int.