# Comparison of Unsigned bit field value with signed values

Tags: c, bit-fields

while writing the code I observe one thing in my code its related to the comparison of bit-field value with negative integers.

I have one structure member of unsigned of size one bit and one unsigned int. When I compare the negative value with unsigned int variable I am getting expected result as 1 but when I compare the structure member with the negative value I am getting the opposite result as 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct S0
{
   unsigned int bit : 1;
};
struct S0 s;

int main (void) 
{
   int negVal = -3;
   unsigned int p = 123;
   printf ("%d\n", (negVal > p)); /*Result as 1 */
   printf ("%d\n", (negVal > s.bit));/*Result as 0 but expected 1 */
   return 0;
}
```

My doubt is if I compare the negative value with unsigned int then balancing will happen (implicit type casting). But if I compare structure member of unsigned int why implicit type casting is not happening. Correct me if I miss any basics of bit fields?

Comment: I'm getting `1` for both on MSVC. What compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc i am using...

Comment: gcc promote `s.bit` to an _int_, so does `(-3 > 0)` valuing 0

Comment: It's a global variable so by default value will be zero

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4) (paragraph 3 in particular)

Comment: partiality duplicate of [Should bit-fields less than int in size be the subject of integral promotion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529080/should-bit-fields-less-than-int-in-size-be-the-subject-of-integral-promotion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For illustration, the following uses a 32-bit `int` and a 32-bit `unsigned int`.

In `negVal > p`:

- `negVal` is an `int` with value −3.
- `p` is an `unsigned int` with value 123.
- C 2018 6.5.8 3, which is discusses `>` and the other relational operators, tells us that the *usual arithmetic conversions* are performed on the operands.
- 6.3.1.8 1 defines the usual arithmetic conversions. For integer types, the first step of the usual arithmetic conversions is to perform the *integer promotions* on each operand.
- 6.3.1.1 2 defines the integer promotions. `int`, `unsigned int`, and integer types wider than these are unchanged. For other integer types, it says: ”If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`.”
- Since `negVal` is an `int`, it is unchanged by the integer promotions.
- Since `p` is an `unsigned int`, it is unchanged by the integer promotions.
- The next step in the usual arithmetic conversions is to convert one operand to the type of the other. For `int` and `unsigned int`, the `int` is converted to `unsigned int`.
- Converting the `int` −3 to `unsigned int` results in 4,294,967,293. (The conversion is defined to add or subtracting `UINT_MAX + 1`, which is 4,294,967,296, to the value as many times as necessary to bring it in range. This is equivalent to “wrapping” modulo 4,294,967,296 or to reinterpreting the two’s complement representation of −3 as an `unsigned int`.)
- After the conversions, the expression `negVal > p` has become `4294967293u > 123u`.
- This comparison is true, so the result is 1.

In `negVal > s.bit`:

- `negVal` is an `int` with value −3.
- `s.bit` is a one-bit bit-field with value 0.
- As above, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands.
- As above, the first step of the usual arithmetic conversions is to perform the integer promotions on each operand.
- Since `negVal` is an `int`, it is unchanged by the integer promotions.
- Since `s.bit` is a bit-field narrower than an `int`, it will be converted by the integer promotions. This one-bit bit-field can represent either 0 or 1. Both of these can be represented by an `int`, and therefore the rule “If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`” applies.
- Converting 0 to `int` results in 0.
- The next step in the usual arithmetic conversions would be to convert one operand to the type of the other. Since both operands are now `int`, no conversion is needed.
- After the conversions, the expression `negVal > s.bit` has become `-3 > 0`.
- This comparison is false, so the result is 0.

Comment: thank you Eric for your clear explanation, out of curiosity I am asking how much bit width is required to typecast s.bit as unsigned integer instead of int because int can hold 32 bits...

Comment: @swaraj: A *cast** is an operator. It has the form `(type)`. When you write `(unsigned int) −3`, that is a cast, and the operation it performs is a conversion. Conversions are also performed in other places. For example, when you write `a = b`, the value of `b` is converted to the type of `a`. Another example is that the integer promotions perform conversions. You should use “cast” to refer to the operator, and you should use “conversion” to refer to any conversion.

Comment: @swaraj: In order for a bit-field declared with `unsigned int` to be promoted to an `unsigned int` and not be promoted to an `int`, it must have as many bits as an `unsigned int` does. If it has fewer bits, then all the values it can represent can also be represented by an `int`, so it will be promoted to an `int`. The number of bits in an `unsigned int` varies from C implementation to C implementation, so there is no single constant size you can declare a bit-field to be to ensure it is promoted to `unsigned int`.

Comment: @swaraj: To ensure that a bit-field is converted to `unsigned int`, you should use a cast: `negVal > (unsigned int) s.bit`.

Answer (score 5):

(move my remark as an answer)

*gcc* promotes `s.bit` to an *int*, so `(negVal > s.bit)` does `(-3 > 0)` valuing 0

See [Should bit-fields less than int in size be the subject of integral promotion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529080/should-bit-fields-less-than-int-in-size-be-the-subject-of-integral-promotion) but your question is not a duplicate of it.

---

`(negVal > p)` returns 1 because *negVal* is promoted to *unsigned* producing a big value, see [Signed/unsigned comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons)

Comment: @Vagish — the signed value is convert to (large) unsigned.

Comment: @bruno—gcc promotes s.bit to an int, but the bit is of type unsigned int and in the draft c++ document it mentioned as "it can be converted to unsigned int if unsigned int can represent all the values of the bit-field", so it should cast to unsigned int right?

Comment: @swaraj the moral of the story is not to make any comparison between signed and unsigned, and for that add the necessary cast to indicate the expected conversion

Comment: @swaraj: The question is tagged C and not C++, so why are you referencing a C++ document?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil - that is the only answer I got for the question, I want answer in c so I didn't accept that just I referred the document

Comment: @swaraj ahhhh yes you are in C and my links are for C++

Comment: @swaraj: C and C++ semantics differ. Using a C++ document to interpret C code can cause errors. In any case, the passage you cite does not indicate that an unsigned bit field is converted to `unsigned int`. It actually says “**otherwise,** it can be converted to `unsigned int`”, and the preceding text says it can be converted to `int` if `int` can represent all the values of the bit field. Since it is a single bit, an `int` can represent all of its values, so it would, if this C++ passage applied, be converted to `int`. The “otherwise” clause about `unsigned int` does not apply.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: yes Eric, that's my mistake only.Do you have any solution/reference for the above question?