# Overflow expected but adding two bytes does not

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

### Update

Can anyone explain the reason for promoting `uint8_t` to `int`? What are the use cases for this behavior? And can I prevent the promoting?

---

I have these very simple code snippets which add two integer types together and print the result. I have compiled those *without any optimization* with `g++ --std=c++11 main.cpp -o test`

```
int main()
{
    uint8_t a = 200, b = 100;
    uint16_t result = (a + b);

    printf("result is %d\n", result);
}
```

Outputs:

> result is 300

I would have expected `(a + b)` to evaluate to `44` because they are both of an 8-bit type and should overflow. But instead I get the unexpected result of `300`.

---

If I re-run the same test with `uint32_t` and `uint64_t`, it is overflowing as expected:

```
int main()
{
    uint32_t a = UINT_MAX, b = UINT_MAX;
    uint64_t result = (a + b);

    printf("result is %ld\n", result);
}
```

Outputs:

> result is 4294967294

Now I can't tell why `uint8_t` is treated differently to `uint32_t`.

Comment: i susptect he means uint23_t a=<some big number>... but cut and paste the wrong line when posting here

Comment: @pm100 yes, as I already stated you're right and i just forgot to paste UINT_MAX there

Comment: Please do not use printf %expected-type

Comment: @DieterLücking Can you state a reason why i shouldn't do this? At the time the printf is called, the result has been evaluated either way. So it's perfectly safe to use this

Comment: Also see [Why must a short be converted to an int before arithmetic operations in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24371868/1708801)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

integral types smaller than int are promoted to int when operations are performed on them

Comment: And what you do with a result has no effect on how that result is computed.

Comment: can you elaborate on why this is the behavior? is it only for speed purposes?

Comment: @BenVoigt that's not correct. I think it is exactly what I asked for. And when `uint8_t` is promoted to 32bit it makes sense why this behavior ocurrs.

Comment: @bricklore: Oh, you're right, I was looking at the second piece of code by mistake.

Comment: Note that the increment and decrement operators do not return promoted values.

Comment: why - i suspect so you can do complicated sums on smaller types without having to worry about overflow

Comment: *when operations are performed on them* is not true of all possible operations.

Answer (score 1):

C++ Standard:
5.10

> — Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both
>   operands. Then the following rules shall be applied to the promoted
>   operands: 
>   — If both operands have the same type, no further conversion
>   is needed.

4.5.1  Integral promotions

> A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or
>   wchar_t whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of
>   int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all
>   the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int.

This is most probably the reason:

3.9.1 Fundamental types

> Plain ints have the natural size suggested by the architecture of the
>   execution environment; the other signed integer types are provided
>   to meet special needs.

Comment: Do you know any reasons for this standard? Just for speed? Or convention?

Comment: Ah okay, so its for the architecture. Thanks