# Is shifting the signed bit of a signed short undefined behaviour in C?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, bit-shift, integer-promotion

I have heard that shifting into signed bit of an integer, i.e.

```
int test = INT_MAX;
test = (test<<1) + 1;
```

is undefined behaviour due to test being greater than INT_MAX. But will this behaviour be encountered in signed short variables, i.e.

```
short test1 = SHRT_MAX;
test1 = (test1<<1) + 1;
```

?

At the moment I have not come across any relevant documentation.

EDIT: I know that undefined behaviour will result in the case of integers, but not of short.

Comment: @Sander I wouldn't call it a duplicate, because `short`s will be promoted to `int`s before shifting, which adds additional complexity here.

Comment: @interjay : fair enough - close vote retracted

Comment: The problem behind the scenes is that the C shift operator is a **'logical shift'**, meaning that it **doesn't care of sign handling**. The promotion between integers follow well known rules that in the specific case, where a `MAX_INT >= MAX_SHORT` should always be true, should guarantee a correct representation of a `short` in an `int`. But when it come to the shift the behavior depends on machine and specific instructions coded by the compiler. I.e. a negative number can become positive right shifted, and the opposite for left shift. But what if CPU uses SAR/SAL arithmetic shifts instead?

Comment: Kind of related [Why must a short be converted to an int before arithmetic operations in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24371868/1708801)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a small integer type is used in most types of expressions, it is [promoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules) to an `int` (if `int` can fit all values of the original type), and the expression is then performed on the `int`.

This gives two possibilites:

1. On a platform where `int` is the same size as `short`, the shift will be undefined behavior because it shifts into the `int`'s sign bit. (More accurately, the reason is that the result cannot be represented as an `int`). See [C11 6.5.7p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p4).
2. On a platform where `int` has more bits than `short`, the shift itself will be successful (though it can be undefined if you're shifting by more than 1). However, when you assign the result back into a `short` variable, the value will not be able to be represented as a `short`. The actual value that will be assigned is implementation-defined. See [C11 6.3.1.3p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3).